# Performance of a sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, oracle11g

I'm exectuting command on large table. It has around 7 millons rows.

Command is like this:

```
select * from mytable;
```

Now I'm restriting the number of rows to around 3 millons. I'm using this command:

```
select * from mytable where timest > add_months( sysdate, -12*4 )
```

I have an index on timest column. But the costs are almost same. I would expect they will decrease. What am I doing wrong?
Any clue?
Thank you in advance!

Here explain plans:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you include execution plan? 
`EXPLAIN PLAN FOR select * from mytable where timest > add_months( sysdate, -12*4 ) `

Comment: What are you looking at that tells you the costs are the same?

Comment: You are retrieving a phenomenal amount of data from Oracle.  That is probably dominating the time for fetching the data.

Comment: You are bringing back 3 of 7 million rows. For Oracle to do an index lookup and then the data fetch would be slower than just running the table. And of course it takes time to read 3 million rows and return them to the client. That is a lot of data to push through a connection. Think about it - if each row contains just 1Kb of data, that's like downloading a 3GB file which would take 5 minutes with a 100MBps internet connection, and that's not including the time to read and discard the other 4GB of data, or time to spool it out to a screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using an index for 3 out of 7 mio. of rows would most probably be even more expensive, so oracle makes a full table scan for both queries, which is IMO correct.

You may try to do parallel FTS (Full Table Scan) - it should be faster, BUT it will put your Oracle server under higher load, so don't do it on heavy loaded multiuser DBs.
Here is an example:

```
select /*+full(t) parallel(t,4)*/ * 
from mytable t
where timest > add_months( sysdate, -12*4 );
```

Comment: Is there no other way to make it faster? using  /*full*/ makes almost no difference.

Comment: what is your main goal? are you spooling this output to file? do you really need ALL this data?

Comment: /*full*/ - will NOT work, it should be: /*+full(t) parallel(t,4)*/ otherwise it will be ignored. Check the execution plan - you should see there 4 parallel workers if hint was understood by CBO (Cost Based Optimizer).

Comment: Oh, ok.  /*+full(t) parallel(t,4)*/ is completely ignored as well... Both commands are getting exactly same execution plan.

Comment: the hint should look like: [select /*+full(table_alias) parallel(table_alias, parallelism)*/ from table table_alias where ...;]  I guess it will be easier if you would post here your _real_ query, so we can see why CBO ignores your hint...

Comment: I understood ;). The command below has same execution plan with and without full-hint . Here the command : `select /*+full(l) parallel(l,4)*/ *  from logs l`

Comment: @MaMu, please execute the following lines and post here the output:
set linesize 200 ;
explain plan for select /*+full(l) parallel(l,4)*/ * from logs l;
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Comment: sorry for late reply. We are not having enterprise edition. Only teh normal one. It has no parallel executions of queries.

Answer (score 2):

To select a *very small number of records from a table use index*. To select a **non-trivial part use partitioning**.

In your case an effective acces would be enabled with range partitioning on `timest` column.

The big advantage is that only relevant partitions are accessed.

Here an exammple

```
create table test(ts date, s varchar2(4000))
PARTITION BY RANGE (ts)
  (PARTITION t1p1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2010-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')),
   PARTITION t1p2 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2015-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')),
   PARTITION t1p4 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
  );
```

Query

```
select * from test where ts < to_date('2009-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd');
```

will access only the paartition 1, i.e. only before '2010-01-01'.

See pstart an dpstop in execution plan

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |      |     5 | 10055 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   1 |  PARTITION RANGE SINGLE|      |     5 | 10055 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |     1 |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL    | TEST |     5 | 10055 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |     1 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("TS"<TO_DATE(' 2009-01-01 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
```

Answer (score -1):

There are (at least) two problems.

1. `add_months( sysdate, -12*4 )` is a function. It's not just a constant, so optimizer can't use index here.
2. Choosing 3 mln. from 7 mln. rows by index is **not** good idea anyway. Yes, you (would) go by index tree fast, yet each time you have to go to the heap (cause you need * = all rows). That means that there's no sense in using this index.

Thus the index plays no role here.

Comment: i think Oracle can use index for "add_months( sysdate, -12*4 )" because this function isn't applied on the table's column, so it should not be the problem. But i'm totally agree with your second statement.

Comment: @MaxU Consider that `sysdate` may potentially change during query execution.

Comment: I'm not able to optimize it using a specific date , for example '01.01.2015'.

Comment: @MaMu And that's because item 2: although optimizer might use index, it decides that full scan is better. And it's right.

Comment: @Matt, sysdate - is a system function which will be evaluated once and its value will be used as a constant/literal by the CBO.